# What are some best practices when passing data to a component in a-frame?

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr

I am quite new to a-frame but am really enjoying creating components and using them as primitives in HTML. In my current project I am creating an a-frame component that creates geometries given a set of vertices. I am creating the component in a generic way so that I can pass it different sets of vertices and create different shapes.

Although this is a specific problem, it speaks to a more general question of what is the suggested way to pass what could be quite big sets of data (objects, arrays) into a component. I would ideally like to be able to pass them from the html layer via a primitive. The amount of data will differ so I cannot hardcode a different property in the schema per item of data.

My current solution is that I have the data available as a global variable. I then pass the name of the variable as a string to the component and convert it to a variable name using `window[variablename]`. To be clear, this is working fine but I am curious to understand if there is a better way (or even just alternative approaches I might try).

Please find below an example of what I am doing;

Here are the bits of data I use in this example;

```
var exampleArraydata = [
    {
        "x":3,
        "y":3,
        "z":5
    },
    {
        "x":0,
        "y":15,
        "z":0
    },
    {
        "x":15,
        "y":0,
        "z":0
    }
]

var exampleObjectdata = {
    "x":3,
    "y":3,
    "z":5
}
```

Here is the example component;

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('examplecomponent', {

    schema: {        
        exampleArray: {type: 'string', default: 'foo'},
        exampleObject: {type: 'string', default: 'bar'},
    },

    init: function (){
       this.testArray = window[this.data.exampleArray]
       this.testObject = window[this.data.exampleObject]
       //logging just to check that it works
       console.log(this.testArray)
       console.log(this.testObject)
       //make geometry with these vec3s...
    }

});
```

Here is the primitive I create with that component;

```
AFRAME.registerPrimitive('a-example', {
  defaultComponents: {
    examplecomponent: {}
  },
  mappings: {
    array: 'examplecomponent.exampleArray',
    object: 'examplecomponent.exampleObject'
  }

});
```

And here is the custom html tag where I pass the variable name as an attribute;

```
<a-example
    array="exampleArraydata"
    object="exampleObjectdata">
</a-example>
```

Again, this does work so if people think that is a good approach then great, but I am new to this and if there are any issues with this I would really appreciate understanding what the issues are and ideally some alternative suggestions. For example, what if the objects were hosted at a URL rather than as a var in my own code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polluting global namespace (window) can lead to problems - you can overwrite important variable one day and it will be difficult to track down, since it won't be `undefined`. The suggested way is to pass data via HTML attribute - as you figured out yourself.

[Noam Almosnino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8005106/noam-almosnino) pointed you in the right direction. You can parse the data however you want, if you want to pass an object into component, just parse its' strigified version:

```
<a-example objectData="{\"x\":3,\"y\":3,\"z\":5}"></a-example>

schema: {
  objectData: {
    default: {},
    parse: function (str) {
      return JSON.parse(str);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tomasz, both yours and Noam's answers help me a great deal. I appreciate you pointing out the issues involved with using window[].

Comment: Always here to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use your own custom parse function to read the data from the 
HTML attribute in particular way.

Here's an example from the docs:
https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/core/component.html#custom-property-type

```
schema: {
  // Parse slash-delimited string to an array (e.g., `foo="myProperty: a/b"` to `['a', 'b']`).
  myProperty: {
    default: [],
    parse: function (value) {
      return value.split('/');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Noam - thats just what I need, I didn't spot that in the docs

Comment: Awesome glad to be of help.